# Woocommerce Customer Login Issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I run woocommerce websites. In one site customers are unable to login/reset their passsword. On /my-account/lost-password/ page is says 'Invalid username or email' (correct).

In db I checked the table wp_wc_customer_lookup have all data but that data is not in wp_users. While my other website's db wp_users have same data of wp_wc_customer_lookup (if this is relevant with the issue).

Can anyone help me in sorting this?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to clear transient data? https://wordpress.org/plugins/transients-manager/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Didn't worked :(